# HTML5 live video Apple iOS

Tags: ios, html, video-streaming, html5-video, http-live-streaming

So as far as I understand it, there is no way (yet) to play live video streams using **HTML5 video** on your Apple device and have **1-1.5** second latency or less. 
The only streaming protocol Apple seems to support is **HLS** and it involves dividing video to chunks, downloading them one by one, and having downloaded enough pieces (**3** by default) start playing it. If each of these pieces is **3** seconds long, then you are looking at **9-10** second latency. Reducing the length of the piece causes constant disruption when streaming and reducing bitrate of the video doesn't seem to reduce the said marker.

Is there any other viable solution for streaming *truly* live video using HTML5 on Apple mobile devices?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If anybody's wondering - there still is a hacky workaround to avoid using HLS at all.

You can convert your video stream into sequence of images in `mpeg1` format (using [ffmpeg](https://www.ffmpeg.org/) for example) and download them at client side using javascript library and use canvas element to display them.  This can be achieved using [jsmpeg](https://github.com/phoboslab/jsmpeg) and its `streaming-server` code than runs on `node.js`

I was able to get 30 fps for `540x320` resolution with **150ms** latency on Safari iOS.

For a precise walk-through see this [blog](http://phoboslab.org/log/2013/09/html5-live-video-streaming-via-websockets) .

Pros:

- improved latency (with adequate bitrate and resolution)
- HTML5 compatibility with *pretty much* cross-platform support

Cons:

- No audio feed.
- increased cpu usage on most handheld devices

Answer (score 0):

No, at the time of this post there is no solution other than `HLS`. Plus if you want to make your own app using another protocol and publish it on the App Store it may be rejected because of the arbitrary [rule 9.4](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/):

> 9.4 Video streaming content over a cellular network longer than 10 minutes must use HTTP Live Streaming and include a baseline 192 kbps or lower HTTP Live stream

There's currently a push for [DASH](http://dashif.org/) which supports low-latency live streaming but Apple is not supporting it.

Comment: I think I might have found a workaround using javascript websockets. more in my answer

Comment: I was aware of the lib but I don't consider it a viable solution for production. MPEG-1 is quite old and missing advanced features present in newer codecs and you're using software (JavaScript) decoding rather the hardware acceleration capabilities of the Apple devices.